# Creating pandas DataFrame from a list of objects and manipulating over these objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of 5 matrices:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a=[(np.random.randint(2,size=(2,3))) for i in xrange(5)]
```

How do I create a pandas DataFrame of 5 records with a single column containing a matrrix for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the dataframe by running :

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'array':a})
```

Output :

```
   array
0  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
1  [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
2  [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
3  [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
4  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

If you want to apply cumsum over the column you can use `apply`

```
df['array']=df['array'].apply(np.cumsum)
```

output:

```
                array
0  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1  [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
2  [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
3  [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
4  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Updated my answer